# Specifying jQuery for auto-assigned IDs?

Tags: php, jquery, unique

In a foreach loop I'm creating some divs (with paragraphs inside gotten from mysql databases). I'd like to make them clickable (/connect them with jquery).

Problem 1: How to create divs with unique IDs?

My solution: Make a counter and use this attribute `id="divclick<?php echo htmlspecialchars($count);?>"`

Problem 2: How to write one jquery to support all divs?

My ***unfinished*** solution:
`$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#divclick").focus(function(){
        $("#buttonoption").animate({width:'toggle'});
      });`

So, how do I tweak the jquery so it reacts to all divs but just one specific #buttonoption is activated according to the div clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Use a shared class and a `data-` attribute.

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mt8Fm/)</kbd>

```
<div data-button="<?php echo $count; ?>" id="divclick<?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?>" class="sharedclass"></div>
```

Then you can bind the click event in jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sharedclass', function() {
    $("#buttonoption" + $(this).data('button')).animate({width:'toggle'});
});
```